# pyinotify not working when using rsync?

Tags: rsync, odoo, pyinotify

It seems changes are not updated when I change files using rsync. I have this rsync script:

```
DEST1="/home/user/odoo8/addons"
DEST2="/home/user/odoo8/addons-bckp"
SRC="/home/user/odoo8/source/***/*"

for DEST in $DEST1 $DEST2; do
    rsync -av --exclude='.git' $SRC $DEST
done
```

I'm running Odoo server with an option `--auto-reload` which lets update python and xml files without having to restart server. If I modify files inside `/home/user/odoo8/addons/`, then it updates even if I don't restart the server. But if I modify antyhing in `source` directory, then do rsync to push changes to `/home/user/odoo8/addons/`, changes are not updated. And it only updates if I restart the server.

Does pyinotify not work if you 'overwrite' files? For example, like using rsync?

Comment: i'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution with rsync? Right now the only solution i can think of is to stop the odoo service. and then write a `git hook` that extracts the `module_name` from the commit message, and then when starting the service again i can just pass `-u extracted_module_name`. But that's a last-ditch option if i can't find any solution.

Comment: I've encountered this as well with pyinotify version 0.9.3-1.1 when writing my own file-monitoring program. As a workaround, I'm using IN_ATTRIB (mask 0x4) rather than IN_MODIFY (mask 0x2) to detect file changes. It detects when modification timestamps are changed, which suits my application just as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default, rsync does not modify the target file, but makes a new temporary file, and then replaces the file when the whole file is transferred, which is probably why the filesystem watcher doesn't detect that the file has changed. I've just had the same problem (with a different autoreloading server), and adding `--inplace` fixed this, but you should consider if `--inplace` is right for you. [rsync manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) has a detailed explaination:

> `--inplace`
>
> This option changes how rsync transfers a file when the file's data
> needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a new
> copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync
> instead writes the updated data directly to the destination file.
>
> This has several effects: (1) in-use binaries cannot be updated
> (either the OS will prevent this from happening, or binaries that
> attempt to swap-in their data will misbehave or crash), (2) the file's
> data will be in an inconsistent state during the transfer, (3) a
> file's data may be left in an inconsistent state after the transfer if
> the transfer is interrupted or if an update fails, (4) a file that
> does not have write permissions can not be updated, and (5) the
> efficiency of rsync's delta-transfer algorithm may be reduced if some
> data in the destination file is overwritten before it can be copied to
> a position later in the file (one exception to this is if you combine
> this option with --backup, since rsync is smart enough to use the
> backup file as the basis file for the transfer).
>
> WARNING: you should not use this option to update files that are being
> accessed by others, so be careful when choosing to use this for a
> copy.
>
> This option is useful for transfer of large files with block-based
> changes or appended data, and also on systems that are disk bound, not
> network bound.
>
> The option implies --partial (since an interrupted transfer does not
> delete the file), but conflicts with --partial-dir and
> --delay-updates. Prior to rsync 2.6.4 --inplace was also incompatible with --compare-dest and --link-dest.